# Find the highest value of y for each x value and connect the points with a line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I am exploring the best way to do this.

I have a scatter plot of y versus x, where x is income per capita.

After plotting all values as a scatter plot, I would like to find the highest value for y for each x value (i.e., at each income level) and then connect these points with a line.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: The question is unrelated to matplotlib. What is the data structure that you plot?

Comment: @DYC I have two columns of data. One for y values and one for x values. I figured I can create a scatter plot. But I'm stuck at the second stage: figure out the highest value of y for each x value and then connecting these points with a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), because it has a convenient [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method and plays well with matplotlib:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                   'y': [3, 7, 9, 4, 1, 2, 8, 6, 4, 4, 3, 1]})

# standard scatter plot
ax = df.plot.scatter('x', 'y')

# find max. y value for each x
groupmax = df.groupby('x').max()

# connect max. values with lines
groupmax.plot(ax=ax, legend=False);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two parallel lists: `x` and `y`. You want to *group* them by `x` and take the maximum in `y`. First, you should sort the lists together. Zip them into a list of tuples and sort:

```
xy = sorted(zip(x, y))
```

Now, group the sorted list by the first element ("x"). The result is a list of tuples where the first element is x and the second is a list of all points with that x. Naturally, each point is also a tuple, and the first element of each tuple is the same x:

```
from itertools import groupby
grouped = groupby(xy, lambda item: item[0])
```

Finally, take the x and the max of the points for each group:

```
envelope = [(xp, max(points)[1]) for xp, points in grouped]
```

`envelope` is a list of `xy` tuples that envelope your scatter plot. You can further unzip it into xs and ys:

```
x1, y1 = zip(*envelope)
```

Putting it all together:

```
x1, y1 = zip(*[(xp, max(points)[1]) 
               for xp, points 
               in groupby(sorted(zip(x, y)), lambda item: item[0])])
```